# Download AsyncRead, AsyncReadProgress event won't fire as internet goes down

Tags: vb6

I use the AsyncRead methode (UserControl.AsyncRead Path, FileType, Key, DownloadType) in VB6 to download a file from internet. Everything works fine except am AsyncReadProgress when the internet goes down while a file is downloading.

The AsyncReadProgress event works the whole time because I can get the AsyncProp.StatusCode. But when the network goes down the AsucnReadProgress event won't fire.

```
Public Sub Download(URL As String, sDestination As String, Optional sId As String = "Id")
    colDest.Add sDestination, sId
    UserControl.AsyncRead URL, vbAsyncTypeFile, sId, vbAsyncReadForceUpdate
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_AsyncReadProgress(AsyncProp As AsyncProperty)
    RaiseEvent Progress(AsyncProp.BytesRead, AsyncProp.BytesMax, AsyncProp.PropertyName)
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_AsyncReadComplete(AsyncProp As AsyncProperty)
    On Error Resume Next

    If AsyncProp.BytesRead > 0 And AsyncProp.BytesRead = AsyncProp.BytesMax Then
        Name AsyncProp.value As colDest.Item(AsyncProp.PropertyName)
    End If

    colDest.Remove AsyncProp.PropertyName
    RaiseEvent Completed(AsyncProp.BytesRead, AsyncProp.BytesMax, AsyncProp.PropertyName)
End Sub
```